# SQL Server trigger on a field that's updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have the following trigger:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @email varchar(200)
DECLARE @jobcode int
DECLARE @status char(1)

DECLARE @emaild varchar(200)
DECLARE @jobcoded int
DECLARE @statusd char(1)

SET @statusd = NULL

SELECT @status = z.status, @email = p.EMail, @jobcode = z.jobID
    FROM zipoutfiles z
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON z.jobID = i.jobID
    INNER JOIN PS_LoginUser AS p ON z.UserID = p.UserID

SELECT @statusd = z.status, @emaild = p.EMail, @jobcoded = z.jobID
    FROM zipoutfiles z
    INNER JOIN deleted AS d ON z.jobID = d.jobID
    INNER JOIN PS_LoginUser AS p ON z.UserID = p.UserID
    WHERE d.jobID = @jobcode


IF ((@status = 'D' AND @statusd = 'R') OR (@status = 'D' AND @statusd = 'E'))
BEGIN
    EXEC SendMail @email, @jobcode
END
END
```

I want to be able to run SendMail when status goes from E to D or R to D, but not D to D (if it gets updated again) and also when it gets inserted as D.  What am I doing wrong here:

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations.  Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always contain exactly one row is generally a bad plan.

Comment: In general: put **as little logic** as possible into your triggers. They fire unexpectedly, more often than anticipated, and you can't control their execution. I would **NEVER** put any processing logic in a trigger. You should at most insert a reminder into another table that an e-mail needs to be sent - but don't do this yourself inside the trigger. Instead, have a separate SQL Server job that checks that table periodically and then asynchronously from your main application sends out those e-mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your table schemas are, but this may get you all of the appropriate emails:

```
select p.EMail as Email, z.JobId as JobCode
  from ZipOutFiles as ZOF inner join
    inserted as i on i.JobId = ZOF.JobId inner join
    PS_LoginUser as PLU on PLU.UserId = ZOF.UserId left outer join
    deleted as d on d.JobId = ZOF.JobId
    where
      ( d.Status = 'E' and i.Status = 'D' ) or -- E -> D.
      ( d.Status = 'R' and i.Status = 'D' ) or -- R -> D.
      ( d.Status is NULL and i.Status = 'D' ) -- Inserted D.
```

I've assumed that you aren't really updating `JobId`.  If so, how do you match the before and after rows?

Also assumed is that `Status` cannot be `NULL`.  If so, the last condition needs to be modified to properly detect no corresponding row was found in the `deleted` table.